# Facebook Registration versus Facebook Login, issue with username and saving user photo

Tags: facebook, registration, facebook-login

I have a web app that has its own user registration, with a handful of users.  The only mandatory fields are email, password and username, which must be unique.  In the long run, I will still want to have our own registration system.

I would like to integrate Facebook, but I'm trying to figure out if I should integrate Facebook Registration or Facebook Login.  I have these questions:

1. I've already started integrating Facebook Login and it works well.  With this, not only can I enable Facebook users to login, but I can get all the information I need to register the user, if he is signing in for the first time via Facebook and has not registered via our site yet.  I do not prompt the user for a password, to simplify the registration, however this means that if the user tries to sign in directly into our site, I tell the user that he must sign in via Facebook Login.  Therefore, I question the need for Facebook Registration, which seems to be more complicated to integrate than Facebook Login.  Can anyone tell me why I should integrate Facebook Registration instead?
2. The drawback I see with integrating Facebook Login or Facebook Registration into our existing user registration, is the username.  I currently copy the user's Facebook username into our database.  However, there is the possibility that the user's Facebook username is missing or is a duplicate of an username from one of our existing users, in which case I will have to prompt the user to change it.  Then what happens if in the future, the user changes his username on Facebook?  Should I change the user's username on our site when he logs in next via Facebook?  What is best practices here?  Am I correct to assume that if I don't bother changing the user's username on our site, it won't be an issue?
3. Then there is the possibility that the user's Facebook username is not valid by our requirements.  Currently, we require the username to be alphanumeric and underscores only, using this reg expression:  /^[\w]*$/  However, Facebook allows periods, but not consecutive special characters and possibly other criteria that I did not detect.  This means that I should use the same validity check as Facebook uses.  Does anyone know Facebook's reg expression for their usernames?
4. I am able to show the Facebook user's profile photo with an IMG tag and src= http://graph.facebook.com/facebook.id/picture.  Does anyone know how to save the photo onto our server?  We use Javascript and PHP.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Hey I'll try to address your points 1 by 1

1. Facebook Login is merely a means to sign a user in to your site by them connecting via Facebook, as you state, they don't have a password as Facebook handles the auth. However you could redirect them to a specific page after using facebook login and get them to enter a password to use their account without being connected to facebook. The facebook registration plugin is more a tool to get users to register on your registration system (although it does support being your only registration system). It provides convenience by pre-populating a number of fields you might commonly ask for such as name etc. if a user is already logged in to Facebook. You can customise though to ask for additional info. It also means you can supply 1 registration form for your users whether or not they use facebook.
2. The facebook username should not be missing. Their 'name' field should be the users first and last name which I believe they have to supply. I don't think it can be empty. What I would actually suggest doing, is what I mentioned in point 1. Allow users to connect via facebook, but then prompt them to enter a username either as part of the login flow or after. You can then check this for uniqueness against your current database. To begin with you could assign them a username that is first_last_timestamp or something similar. This would more likely encourage them to change their username to something they want. If you used the registration plugin, you could easily enter your own "username" field into this. Then it doesn't matter if the user changes their name on facebook as they would still have a unique username to your site.
3. Facebook's usernames should just be a users first and last name (though obviously people do enter random things). The 'name' field is an combination of these so there will most likely be a space between them. You could always replace any invalid characters using your own regex, replace whitespace with underscores etc.
4. I'm not sure if there are any platform policies that would restrict you from saving the users picture to your own server/DB. What I would ask though is why you would want to? In my experience this is more likely to change then their name is. As such groups of friends using your site are probably more likely to recognise the profile pic that their friends use on facebook.

I would finally say, that the best bit about connecting their Facebook account either way means you can provide a smooth login experience so that a user doesn't have to sign in everytime. My own personal experience is that facebook login (with your own integration code on the success page) is better than the registration plugin. There are fewer steps for a user to connect to your app this way and they don't have to fill out a form. The success callback also means you can still perform the custom username code/flow I mentioned above and then prompt them to change their username if they desire. Just remember it is best to ask for as little info as possible at sign-up as users are more likely to join this way.

Hope this helps!